# Creating a geoserver layer with curl (but with a bounding box)

Tags: geoserver, curl

I'm attemping to load a layer into Geoserver from a PostGIS database using cURL.
It works, but I also need to set the bounding box to -180,-90,180,90.  Does anyone know how to add the bounding box to the below command?

curl -v -u xxx:xxx -X POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d `"<featureType><name>Airports</name></featureType>"` http://xxx.xx.com:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/PostGIS/datastores/PostGIS/featuretypes

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Ended up solving the problem like this...

curl -v -u xx:xx -X POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" 
-d `"<featureType><name>Airports</name><latLonBoundingBox><minx>-180</minx><maxx>180</maxx><miny>-90</miny><maxy>90</maxy><crs>EPSG:4326</crs></latLonBoundingBox></featureType>"`
http://xx.xxx.com:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/PostGIS/datastores/PostGIS/featuretypes